# Handling JSON circular reference exception in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, json.net

So I'm playing around with Web API in ASP.NET 5. At some point my app stopped working, only showing "Bad Gateway" IIS error page (I run it in IIS Express, by F5). It took me a while to figure out what the problem was - I introduced a circular reference into a class one of my Web API methods returns, like this:

```
public class CircularParent
{
    public CircularChild Data;

    public CircularParent()
    {
        Data = new CircularChild(this);
    }
}

public class CircularChild
{
    public CircularParent Owner { get; set; }

    public CircularChild(CircularParent owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

The result is `JsonSerializationException`. My question is not how to solve it, but rather how to deal with such a situation in future. How can I handle such an exception? Or at least how to log it or just see it logged somewhere? `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` does not help. `UseExceptionHandler(errorApp => errorApp.Run(...))` does not help either, the execution doesn't get into `errorApp.Run()`. The debugger does not break at the exception. All I get with IIS is that rather uninformative "Bad Gateway" page.

Comment: I know its probably a non-answer, but Newtonsofts json.net can handle circular references in a number of ways and can be configured as the default JSON serializer for ASP.Net

Answer (score 15):

Try to add `Newtonsoft.Json` in the latest version [8.0.1-beta3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/8.0.1-beta3) to dependencies in `package.json` and to use use

```js
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

See [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3818) for more details.

Comment: As I mentioned, my question is not about how to fix the issue, but rather about how to handle or at least log this kind of exception. I think there are other "uncatchable" exceptions like this and I'd like to know how to deal with it in future.

Comment: @Dmitry: I'm not sure that I correctly understand your goals. The old version `Newtonsoft.Json` either generate wrong exception or to crash the HTTP Platform Handler. As the result you get exception "HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway". You can just set breakpoint to any web method and to hold the execution tor one min. You will see the error "HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway" on the client side. Thus one can have a lot of reasons why you could get Bad Gateway error.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it crashes httpPlatformHandler. When I hold execution in the debugger I get the same error page "HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway". How can I deal with this kind of situation? For instance, returning to the JsonSerializationException case, I took me quite a while just to see the exception itself. I had to run the project from console with DNX and Kestrel. In IIS I just got that IIS error page from which it's hard to say what's going on. The exception is not caught by usual ASP.NET means. So I'm asking for some info on how you are supposed to diagnose and treat problems like this.

Comment: @Dmitry: It's not easy to debug some errors. You should just know that **hanging of the server** HTTP Platform Handler, which process all requests to ASP.NET 5 application in external process, produce the error HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway. If you can see that your Web Api method are finished without any problem and you can see *later* HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway then it should be mostly not your error, but it could be problem in MVC6 code or the code HTTP Host which both are still in  RC phase.

Comment: Yeah, some errors are harder to debug than others :). But is it least possible to see the exception logged somewhere? I can't find any traces of it, basically. The "HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway" error page has 'Request Tracing Directory' link that points to the TraceLogFiles folder, there are some XML files in it, but no mention of the exception in them.

Comment: @Dmitry: Sorry, but I still don't full follow your goals. One make HTTP request to IIS from the web browser. The IIS starts HTTP Platform Handler as external program (CGI interface) and forward to that. IIS can detect timeout of HTTP Platform Handler. IIS (not any your code) send the error HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway to the web browser. So the HTTP Platform Handler, MVC and your program could works correctly, but too slow and one will get the error HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway. It's clear that one will don't see any exception in debugger in case of the above scenario.

Comment: What he is asking is how to actually see the exception which is causing IIS to show the HTTP 502.3 Bad Gateway Error page. The actual error page isn't that helpful because it doesn't give you any real information about why you are getting an error.  At the moment, this is because IIS does not have its own output window. And, as you have discovered, the best way to see exceptions is to run it from the console.

Comment: @BlakeMumford: Sometimes it helps additional code like `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`, `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();` or `loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));`, `loggerFactory.AddDebug();`, but in other cases **no** such changes helps with the current code of ASP.NET 6. Just set breakpoint in some Action  somewhere and wait for 1 min. You will see already "Bad Gateway" message from IIS, but the CGI program dnx.exe will stil run and it's later output will not seen more.

Comment: @BlakeMumford: Which problem you have exactly? **Can you share small project which can be used to reproduce the problem, which you see?** It can be that the current error handling is not clean enough or you don't activated logging correctly. It could be just that you used wrong *order* of inserting middleware components in `Configure` function. Verify that the line like `loggerFactory.AddConsole(minLevel:LogLevel.Verbose);` is the first in `Configure` and the next are `loggerFactory.AddDebug(); app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` and `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();`

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core:

```
var mvc = services.AddMvc(options =>
{
   //mvc options
});

mvc.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For  ASP.NET Core 2.2 use the Configure method in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you still get circular reference when serializing with this setting?

Comment: It worked for me, i was using .Net 5. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be a roundabout way, but I did a db first migration that had allot of virtual properties, while it worked it would result in circular references. I resolved this by adding

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

(Newtonsoft in my case) to all the virtual properties and it worked well.