# Self referencing loop detected in ASP.Net Core 1.1 Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, object-graph

Though I have followed the article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753498/self-referencing-loop-detected-in-asp-net-core) I keep getting the error

> self referencing loop detected for property '...' with type '...'. Path '[4]....[0]'.

I have added this to my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(opt => 
        opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
            ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
```

What else could cause the reference loop error ?

EDIT:
Answer to question in comments...
The affected classes are:

```
public partial class GuidingSymptom
    {
        public GuidingSymptom()
        {
            VideosGuidingSymptoms = new HashSet<VideosGuidingSymptoms>();
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(70)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int SeverityId { get; set; }
        public int? DiagnoseId { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("GuidingSymptom")]
        public virtual ICollection<VideosGuidingSymptoms> VideosGuidingSymptoms { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DiagnoseId")]
        [InverseProperty("GuidingSymptom")]
        public virtual Diagnose Diagnose { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SeverityId")]
        [InverseProperty("GuidingSymptom")]
        public virtual GuidingSymptomSeverity Severity { get; set; }
    }

public partial class VideosGuidingSymptoms
{
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
    public int GuidingSymptomId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuidingSymptomId")]
    [InverseProperty("VideosGuidingSymptoms")]
    public virtual GuidingSymptom GuidingSymptom { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VideoId")]
    [InverseProperty("VideosGuidingSymptoms")]
    public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of the offending class

Comment: @Nkosi added answer to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution which is to add

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

annotation to the affected property. However, I expected that this would not be necessary when using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

Answer (score 2):

Some serialization frameworks do not allow such cycles. For example, Json.NET will throw the following exception if a cycle is encountered.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Blog' with type 'MyApplication.Models.Blog'.
```

If you are using ASP.NET Core, you can configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the `ConfigureServices(...)` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data