# Returning .NET MVC model as JSON results in Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a web app from the .NET Web Application template. This app should display heroes and their superpowers.

This is my **controller** method:

```
public IActionResult GetHero(int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Hero hero = _context.Hero.Include(m => m.SuperPowers).Single(m => m.Id == id);

        if (hero == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return Json(hero);
    }
```

And this is my **model**:

```
public class Hero
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SuperPower> SuperPowers { get; set; }
}
```

If I use

```
return Json(hero);
```

like in the controller code above I get a "Bad Gateway" error but if I use

```
return View(hero);
```

I can display the hero and the related superpowers in a view that I created.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try remove your breakpoints (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420397/handling-json-circular-reference-exception-in-asp-net-5)

Comment: A little of topic but 'Hero` class is not considered as a `Model` but rather as a data structure

Comment: Should your action not be: `public JsonResult GetHero(int id)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
return Json(hero, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed) for why this is important. `GET` requests are deny by default:

> By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. If you need to send JSON in response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as the second parameter to the Json method. However, there is a chance a malicious user can gain access to the JSON payload through a process known as JSON Hijacking. You do not want to return sensitive information using JSON in a GET request. For more details, see Phil's post at http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx/.

Comment: just `Json` `return JsonResult(hero, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` ?

Comment: I get "Cannot resolve symbol JsonRequestBehavior", however this does not work either: return Ok(hero);

Comment: @KarlEriksson It's part of the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace so it should resolve: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```