# Can I use Jobject with OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I know that Newtonsoft Json can serialize and deserialize object. Is it possible to write customn serializator and expand Odata serializator functinallity.
Will it work for filtering, paging and other options of Odata URL Parser?
Because now I get an exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: **ODataResourceSerializer cannot write an object of type 'Collection(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)'.**
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.GetResourceType(Object graph, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteResource(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext, IEdmTypeReference expectedType)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteComplexAndExpandedNavigationProperty(IEdmProperty edmProperty, SelectItem selectItem, ResourceContext resourceContext, ODataWriter writer)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteComplexProperties(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, ResourceContext resourceContext, ODataWriter writer)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteResource(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext, IEdmTypeReference expectedType)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatterHelper.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataVersion version, Uri baseAddress, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, IWebApiUrlHelper internaUrlHelper, IWebApiRequestMessage internalRequest, IWebApiHeaders internalRequestHeaders, Func`2 getODataMessageWrapper, Func`2 getEdmTypeSerializer, Func`2 getODataPayloadSerializer, Func`1 getODataSerializerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Details:

I have DTO object with Jobject property

```
 public class ContentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JObject Content { get; set; }
}
```

In JObject I use Newtonsoft Json to save concrete content type as this:

```
private JObject GetContentAsync(ContentType contentType, int contentID)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() } };
        if (contentType == ContentType.FAQ)
        {
            var faq = GetFaq(contentID, contentType);
            return JObject.FromObject(faq,JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
        }
        if (contentType == ContentType.Announcement)
        {
            var annoncement = GetAnnouncement(contentID, contentType);
            return JObject.FromObject(annoncement, JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

In this code I add Jobject propery to my ContenModel

```
 public ContentDto GetContentByIdWithTranslation(int contentId, ContentType contentType)
    {

        return new ContentDto
        {
            Content = GetContentAsync(contentType, contentId)

        };

    }
```

And this ifs for example my FAQMOdel

```
 public class FaqModel
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string MainTag { get; set; }
}
```

And than in startup I Build an EDM model

```
 private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {


        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<ContentDto>("Content").EntityType.Name = "Content";

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

And trying to get OData endpoint as this

```
  app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter().Count().MaxTop(10);
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
```

But than If I go to link https://localhost:5001/odata/Content
That is my controller method

```
 [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]

    public ActionResult<IQueryable<ContentDto>> Get()//int contentId, ContentType contentType
    {
        var data = contentService.GetAllContent();
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

In service:

```
public IQueryable<ContentDto> GetAllContent()
    {
        List<ContentDto> resultList = new List<ContentDto>();
        var list = context.Contents;
        foreach( var entityContent in list)
        {
            var model = GetContentByIdWithTranslation(entityContent.Id, entityContent.ContentType);
            resultList.Add(model);
        }
        return resultList.AsQueryable();

    }
```

But I get only this result in browser

> {"@odata.context":"https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#Content","value":[{"Id":0,"Content":[

UPDATE ___________________________________

Language and State is simple enums.

```
  public enum ContentType
        {
            FAQ,
            Announcement
        }

        public enum Language
        {
            UA,
            EN
        }
        public enum State
        {
            Modified,
            Published,
            Deleted
        }
```

Method call to database to get announcement and faq

```
 public IQueryable<AnnouncementModel> GetAnnouncement()
        {
            var model = from content in context.Contents
                            //join translation in context.ContentTranslations on content.Id equals translation.ContentId
                        join announcement in context.Announcements on content.Id equals announcement.ContentId
                        where content.ContentType == ContentType.Announcement
                        select new AnnouncementModel()
                        {
                            ContentId = content.Id,
                            State = content.State,
                            Header = announcement.Header,
                            ValiUntil = announcement.ValiUntil
                        };
            return model;
        }



        public FaqModel GetFaq(int contentId, ContentType contentType)
        {
            var model = (from content in context.Contents
                         //join translation in context.ContentTranslations on content.Id equals translation.ContentId
                         join faq in context.FAQs on content.Id equals faq.ContentId
                         where content.ContentType == ContentType.FAQ
                         && content.Id == contentId
                         select new FaqModel()
                         {
                             ContentId = content.Id,
                             State = content.State,
                             MainTag = faq.Tag
                         })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            return model;
        }
```

Comment: Did your response json is not complete?If so,be sure to set ReferenceLoopHandling=Ignore.Reference:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60202991/11398810.   What is your `ContentType` and `State`?Also,how do you define `GetFaq` and `GetAnnouncement`?

Comment: I have updated question. Response is not complete because OData not working with plain json. If it possible to create serializator for Jobject to diplay it. And doest OData will work with Jobject if I add customn serializator ( fucntions call like $expend , $ select and so on)?