# How to avoid cyclic relationships in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have these tables:

[image]

On the other hand, I have a Web API that returns an entity `Trabajador` whose primary key is specified.

The problem I have is that when loading `TurnoPorTrabajador` entities, a JSON error occurs since `TurnoPorTrabajador` includes `Trabajador` which, in turn, also contains `TurnoPorTrabajador`, and so on, ad infinitum.

I do this in EF Core 8; this was my last attempt:

```
public async Task<Trabajador?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    var turnos = await db.TurnoPorTrabajador
            .Where(tt => tt.TurnoPorTrabajadorElminadoEn == null && tt.TrabajadorId == id)
            .ToListAsync();
    var trabajador = await db.Trabajador
        .Include(t => t.Ubicacion.Where(u => u.UbicacionEliminadoEn == null))
        .Include(t => t.Area.Where(a => a.AreaEliminadoEn == null))
        .FiltraEmpresaCliente(this, t => t.ExtEmpresaId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TrabajadorEliminadoEn == null && t.TrabajadorId == id);

    if (trabajador != null)
        trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador = turnos;

    return trabajador;
}
```

At first, I had an `Include` in the main query, but, lastly, I tried to do separate queries but the same problem happens.

When I retrieve `turnos`, it does not return `Trabajador` relationship, but when executing that if, `Trabajador` entity is returned also.

The JSON error is this for you to better understand the problem:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Data.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TurnoPorTrabajador.Trabajador.TrabajadorId.
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)

`$.Data` is of `Trabajador` entity type.

Since this is returned by the Web API, I cannot control how the object is json serialized.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

by using:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve)
```

Any JSON object cannot be converted to object. If I add those options, some weird properties are added to the JSON string, making impossible to convert to a C# object;

> ValueKind = Object :
> "{"$id":"2","$values":[{"$id":"3","clienteId":15,"ciudadId":66,"tipoDocumentoId":1,
> ......

Notice the properties preceeded by `$`.

Comment: Why don't you change the settings for json serialization? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34421722/11238626

Comment: @Miraziz I have problem only with this query. If I do the change globally, maybe some mistake could be hidden.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid or control circular references in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985907/avoid-or-control-circular-references-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Json serialization is not EF Core concern. Relationships represented by navigation properties are part of the data model. Configure Json serializer, or use DTOs instead of entities.

Comment: @GuruStron by using that JSON option (`ReferenceHandler.Preserve`), this side effect occurs. This JSON object cannot be deserialized to object: `ValueKind = Object : "{"$id":"2","$values":[{"$id":"3","clienteId":15,"ciudadId":66,"tipoDocumentoId":1, ......`. That `$id` and `$values` properties are not present if no JSON option is set. Without that option, this JSON object is to be converted: `ValueKind = Array : "[{"clienteId":15,"ciudadId":66,"tipoDocumentoId":1,"guid":"31fad9af-49b5-4a2f-bbf8-ac31df596f8c","tin":"555555555",...`. Notice also `$id` property, added only if I use that option.

Comment: @GuruStron So is it possible to generate navigation properties only 1 level in the query?

Comment: @jstuardo try using `IgnoreCycles` option. But in general - just use a special class (DTO) to return from the controller.

Comment: Preserve references will only work so long as the deserializer recognizes the reference pattern used, so for instance MS's JSON Serializer or Newtonsoft. Deserializing via JS or other consumers won't recognize it. The best option is generally to create DTOs for the JSON structure you want. Entities are there to serve the needs of the data domain, not transport.